# OAuth2RestTemplate with custom ErrorHandler

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

i have configured an OAuth2RestTemplate with a custom error handler with which i want to disable the default behaviour of throwing an Exception if the status is 4xx or 5xx (i want to check the HttpStatus on the ResponseEntity itself)

The implementation looks like this

```
@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resourceDetails) {
    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails);
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
            // nothing to do
        }
    });
    return restTemplate;
}
```

When a request results in Status 409 (Conflict) i always get the following exception:

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   POST request for "http://localhost:10010/...": stream is closed;
>   nested exception is java.io.IOException: stream is closed

Is there any way to avoid this exception? If i remove the custom error handler the there will be a HttpClientErrorException

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 409 Conflict

Thanks for any responses :)

Best regards,

Bernhard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve been able to get around the exception being thrown by creating a custom subclass of OAuth2ErrorHandler and using that instead of a custom ResponseErrorHandler. OAuth2RestTemplate checks explicitly if the errorHandlers are instanceof OAuth2ErrorHandler.

You should only have to override the hasError method:

```java
public class NoOpResponseErrorHandler extends OAuth2ErrorHandler {
    NoOpResponseErrorHandler(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource) {
        super(resource);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        return response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) ||
                response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

To use it with `OAuth2RestTemplate`, you'll need to pass in your `OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails` object (ie. `ClientCredentialsResourceDetails`).

```
OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails);
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new NoOpOAuthErrorHandler(resourceDetails));
```

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.java#L97-L103

Comment: I don't think you need to extend OAuth2ErrorHandler. You can set a custom response error handler to an OAuth2ErrorHandler instance: i.e. restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorHandler(customErrorHandler, oAuthDetails()));

Comment: What advantage do we gain by following this approach rather than create a sub class of OAuth2Erro...?